# Why are struct and class essentially the same in C++?

Tags: history, language-design, c++

`struct` and `class` in C++ are nearly identical (as covered for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/92859/1717300)).

But why is this so? What did happen when C++ was developed and eventually standardized, that `struct` was allowed to define a full OOP class, yet `class` keyword was *also* added? There must be a historical reason for this, but I did not find an answer by searching.

In contrast, for example [C# uses these keywords too](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13049/1717300), but there they have different and distinct meaning. I would say this is quite a valuable feature in that language.

In hindsight, it would have for example made sense to keep C++ `struct` be always compatible with similar C `struct` in memory layout, and only those class features that are compatible with that would have been supported (so no "virtual" stuff, value always copyable by `memcpy`, maybe even some kind of C interoperability for `struct` methods). Or something else perhaps; point is, the distinction could have meant something and added to the language, instead of being a (small) source of confusion it is now.

So I am looking for some historical record, quote or story, which would explain this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Bjarne Stroustrup writes in his [The Design and Evolution of C++](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201543303) book (item 3.5.1):

> At this point, the object model becomes real in the sense that an object is more 
>   than the simple aggregation of the data members of a class. An object of a C++ class with a virtual function is a fundamentally different beast from a simple C `struct`. 
>   Then why did I not at this point choose to make structs and classes different notions?
>
> My intent was to have a single concept: a single set of layout rules, a single set of lookup rules, a single set of resolution rules, etc. Maybe we could have lived with 
>   two sets of rules, but a single concept provides a smoother integration of features and 
>   simpler implementations. I was convinced that if `struct` came to mean "C and compatibility" to users and `class` to mean "C++ and advanced features" the community would fall into two distinct camps that would soon stop communicating. Being able to use as many or as few language features as needed when designing a class was an important idea to me. Only a single concept would support my ideas of a smooth and gradual transition from "traditional  C-style  programming," through  data abstraction, to object-oriented programming. Only a single concept would support the notion of "you only pay for what you use" ideal.
>
> In retrospect, I think these notions have been very important for C++'s success as a practical tool. Over the years, just about everybody has had some kind of expensive idea that could be implemented "for classes only," leaving low overhead and low features to `struct`s. I think the idea of keeping `struct` and `class` the same concept saved us from classes supporting an expensive, diverse, and rather different set of features than we have now. In other words, the "a `struct` is a `class`" notion is what has stopped C++ from drifting into becoming a much higher-level language with 
>   a disconnected low-level subset. Some would have preferred that to happen.

Comment: Excellent. I'll wait a bit before accepting in case other answers are written. (And personally I am not sure I agree with his rationale, but that's beside the point nad off-topic.)

Comment: The “disconnection” he refers to happened with Objective-C exactly for the same reason, and for me, coming from C++, it was one of the major downpoints (even though I pretty much enjoyed it)